# How to move a firefox window with pywinauto

Tags: python, automated-tests, pywinauto

Here is my code :

The commented part is what I tried earlier, but didn't work.

```
    try:
        # app = Application(backend="uia").start("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
        # time.sleep(5)
        # mozilla = app.window_(title_re = ".*Mozilla Firefox")
        # time.sleep(5)
        # mozilla.move_window(200, 200, 200, 200, True)
        app = Application().start("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
        dlg_spec = app.window()
        dlg_spec.move_window(x=None, y=None, width=200, height=100, repaint=True)
    except AppStartError:
        print("CANNOT START !!")
        return False
    except ElementNotFoundError : 
        print("COULD NOT FOUND THE WINDOW !!")
        return False
    except ElementAmbiguousError :
        print("TOO MANY FIREFOX !!")
        return False
```

I get COULD NOT FOUND THE WINDOW !!
And in the commented one I get this error :

```
    mozilla.move_window(200, 200, 200, 200, True)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 180, in __call__
    raise AttributeError("Neither GUI element (wrapper) " \
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'move_window' were found (typo?)
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What `dlg_spec.wrapper_object()` returns?

Comment: When I try```dlg_spec.wrapper_object()``` on the part where I get this error, it doesn't give it anymore. I get    ```except ElementNotFoundError : 
        print("COULD NOT FOUND THE WINDOW !!")
        return False```

Comment: Yes, because you have to use proper `title` or `best_match` value inside `.window(...)` call. For example, `app.window(title_re=".*Firefox")`. To list all the titles use this statement: `print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use proper `title` or `best_match` value inside `.window(...)` call. So that pywinauto knows which window to search. For example, `app.window(title_re=".*Firefox")`.

To list all the titles use this statement:

```
print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])
```

Also `.draw_outline()` is useful method to highlight found element.

Recommended reading: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

---

EDIT:

If `.windows()` returns an empty list, you have to re-connect by title using method `connect` instead of / in addition to `start`. We have a feature request to detect spawned processes, but it's of low priority for now.

EDIT2:

How it works for me:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="win32").start("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(title='Mozilla Firefox', found_index=0, timeout=5)
dlg_spec = app.window(title='Mozilla Firefox', found_index=0)
dlg_spec.move_window(x=None, y=None, width=200, height=100, repaint=True)
```

Comment: Yes I tried with ```app.window(title_re=".*Firefox")``` it's commented on my post, I also just tried your suggestion ```print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])``` but it returns ```[]```

Comment: Oh, that means Firefox spawns child process with the target tab. You have to re-connect by title using method `connect` instead of `start`. We have a feature request to detect spawned processes, but it's of low priority for now.

Comment: Ok thanks now I can print ```the window_text()``` but still I can't move the window, I get : ```AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'wrapper_object' were found (typo?)```

Comment: It's typical message when the element is not found. Please make sure you're using correct `Application` object and correct `window(title="...")` specification using `.wrapper_object()` method.

Comment: ```for w in app.windows():
            titre = w.window_text() 
        mozilla = Application(backend="uia").connect(title=titre)
        mozilla.wrapper_object()``` Even after that I get the same error I checked the title by printing it, it is Mozilla Firefox. Isn't that right ?

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, now I'm trying this one ```app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re = ".*Firefox")
        time.sleep(5) 
        for w in app.windows():
            titre = w.window_text() 
        print(titre)
        mozilla = app.window(title=titre)
        time.sleep(3)
        print(mozilla.wrapper_object())``` and this returns ```uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Mozilla Firefox', Dialog``` But the move_window still doesn't work

Comment: `move_window` is available for `backend="win32"` only

Comment: ```mozilla = Application(backend="win32").connect(title=Mozilla Firefox)``` still the same error message

Comment: I've added working code to the answer. The `timeout` param is needed in `connect(...)` method. Maybe `found_index=0` is needed if there are several instances of Firefox.